# How can you return things multiple times?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

```js
function openOrSenior(data){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i][0] >= 55 && data[i][1] >=7){
      return "Senior"
    } else {
      return "Open"
    }
  }    
}

openOrSenior([[45, 12],[55,21],[19, -2],[104, 20]])
```

So what I'm trying to do is to see if its should say senoir or open. If the first value in the array is 55 or above and the second value in the array is above seven, then you should return senior, else return open. But it only returns 1 anwser, which is the anwser for `[45,12]`. How do you make it so that it returns the anwser for every array?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the desired result of `openOrSenior`?

Comment: Seems like you need to use Generator functions or a Promise with a trick. Please explain the requirement in detail

Comment: Your function will need to generate an array and return that, you are returning the last result from the parameter array.

Comment: Re above comments, there's nothing in this post that suggests the need of generators or promises.

Comment: @MarkB by last, you mean first.

Comment: Yes sorry first not last as only the first element is evaluated

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to see if the age is over 55(the first element of the array) and the disability is over 7. for example [ 65, 10] should return senior. If not it should return open. The problem I'm having is, if i add multiple arrays, it only tells what the first array is, which in this case is Open. But it should say open senior, open senior.

Comment: @EthanAgar So your expected result is an array like `[ "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Senior" ]`, right? Use `map`, as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to return an array, but you return a string.
Instead of immediately returning after iterating the first element in the input array, iterate all elements in the input and return an array containing each input element's result.

```js
function openOrSenior(data) {
  return data.map(item =>
    item[0] >= 55 && item[1] >= 7 ? 'Senior' : 'Open');
}

let out = openOrSenior([
  [45, 12],
  [55, 21],
  [19, -2],
  [104, 20]
]);

console.log(out);
```